# What is 'oadm' in CLI?

Tags: openshift-origin

I'm busy with OpenShift V3 and for some stuff I need to do commands like:

```
oadm registry --config=admin.kubeconfig \
    --credentials=openshift-registry.kubeconfig 

oadm router <router_name> --replicas=<number> \
    --credentials='/etc/openshift/master/openshift-router.kubeconfig' \
    --service-account=router
```

The question is: I don't know the meaning of `'oadm'` and why I have to use it in this case? In OpenShift itself I have to use `'oc'` so it's probably not a command specific for OpenShift.

Comment: You can also use `oc adm ...` instead of `oadm ...`.  I think they're equivalent, don't know if there is any reason to prefer one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`oadm` is an OpenShift command that is focused on admin level tasks that usually require elevated cluster authority to run.  `oc` is an OpenShift command that is focused on common user level activities.

For instance, the `oadm registry` and `oadm router` commands both require edit privileges inside the "default" namespace.  Most common users should not have that authority, so the commands are considered elevated.  You'll also notice commands like `oadm policy add-cluster-role-to-*` and `oadm manage-node` which are other admin level tasks.

Comment: Came across this but for OpenShift V4, and the cli now has it inside.. eg, `oc adm`.